# how to make request in python instead of curl

Tags: python, curl

Here is the curl command:

```
curl 'http://ecard.bupt.edu.cn/User/ConsumeInfo.aspx' 
-H 'Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=4mzmi0whscqg4humcs5fx0cf; .NECEID=1; .NEWCAPEC1=$newcapec$:zh-CN_CAMPUS; .ASPXAUTSSM=A91571BB81F620690376AF422A09EEF8A7C4F6C09978F36851B8DEDFA56C19C96A67EBD8BBD29C385C410CBC63D38135EFAE61BF49916E0A6B9AB582C9CB2EEB72BD9DE20D64A51C09474E676B188D937B84E601A981C02F51AA9C85A08EABCC1D30D7B9299E02A45D427B08A44AEBB0' 
-H 'Origin: http://ecard.bupt.edu.cn' 
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' 
-H 'Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4' 
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' 
-H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Referer: http://ecard.bupt.edu.cn/User/ConsumeInfo.aspx' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
--data '__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUINDEyMzA5NDkPFgIeCFNvcnRUeXBlBQNBU0MWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgQPPCsAEQMADxYEHgtfIURhdGFCb3VuZGceC18hSXRlbUNvdW50ZmQBEBYAFgAWAAwUKwAAFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCAgEPZBYCAgEPDxYEHghDc3NDbGFzcwUKU29ydEJ0X0FzYx4EXyFTQgICZGQYAQUiY3RsMDAkQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyMSRncmlkVmlldw88KwAMAQhmZBb11RlvPBlQn5fbuqe6uh8BRZJ2jUZ5U17xEnRM%2BnbF&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=D99777FC&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAgtbl4l0SdCQqYpyy3Ex39BEoHXgPeD%2Fa3eEKPr2bG0rY8WyuyQajjUbeopYM%2Fne68pyn2l0BPEWPPnyd6MfoDZVQGbFRIKjb%2FOTPkkCDIIaJ3X6W3VKO%2FV036Pdf6jf06OTFulzGhY80%2FZ1HbCJJ6LR5Lg6mLp72ibUCB3VipRJuK11qmW%2BSDe3IOvbK4oNUdV5%2FxmkXw25tTwfJ8P8OS2&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24rbtnType=0&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtStartDate=2016-09-17&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtEndDate=2016-09-24&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24btnSearch=%E6%9F%A5++%E8%AF%A2' --compressed
```

I want to use request to get the return message to analyse, but i'm confused about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module. The answer would be something like:

```
response = requests.get('http://ecard.bupt.edu.cn/User/ConsumeInfo.aspx', 
    headers={'Origin': 'http://ecard.bupt.edu.cn'}, 
    data={'__EVENTTARGET': '', 'rbtnType':0}, 
    cookies={'.NECEID': 1}
)
```

I didn't put all parameters there but I think this example is enough to figure out how to send exact the same request you want. The only thing I am not sure is `--compressed` flag - as I understand from docs it is something more specific to curl(correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: First of all, thank u for ur reply. In fact, this problem doesn't happend in the send the request. I used curls in command window can get the same info  as the browser but when i convert the curl to request，and run the code, it failed. That's what i am confused.What's more, the website use Ajax,so i cannot find which parameters it send.

Comment: @W.LeeLom, for emultaing AJAX request you can add "X-Requested-With : XMLHttpRequest" to headers

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful website to convert the curl to requests:
[curl to request](http://curl.trillworks.com/)

Curl Command:

```
curl 'http://js.t.sinajs.cn/open/api/js/api/bundle.js?version=20150130.02' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://www.liaoxuefeng.com/wiki/001374738125095c955c1e6d8bb493182103fac9270762a000/001375502200090e998439175cc4268b0ea703b3b4ed55e000' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --compressed
```

Python requests:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'http://www.liaoxuefeng.com/wiki/001374738125095c955c1e6d8bb493182103fac9270762a000/001375502200090e998439175cc4268b0ea703b3b4ed55e000',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

requests.get('http://js.t.sinajs.cn/open/api/js/api/bundle.js?version=20150130.02', headers=headers)
```